# Search text inside array of strings that can be split to multiple strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have array like this:

```
["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac \
 dui porta, varius augue ut, rhoncus orci. Ut vitae sem est. Etiam \
 metus metus, convallis vel nibh ut, congue feugiat ipsum. Donec \
 quis nibh vulputate, vulputate quam eu, lacinia enim. Nunc ipsum \
 urna, fermentum id mi quis, varius sagittis est. Suspendisse et \
 pulvinar ipsum. ", "Sed id libero eros.", " In condimentum \
          ^                                                ^
 euismod scelerisque. Donec dapibus vulputate dolor, nec aliquet\
 massa blandit interdum."]
```

And I need to search for string that can span into multiple strings like:

```
"ipsum. Sed id libero eros. In condimentum"
```

which can be found inside the array (marked with ^), I've try to search using substring and indexOf that will not work since "ipsum. " can be found in two places. Here is my try:

I have little bit different code because actually I need to search the DOM and create Range object, but search through the array is more generic and it will help me write my code.

I need the begining of the text with offset and index in array and the end of the string with offset of the end with index (so I can create Range object). The whole text can also be inside single string.

Anyone know the algorithm that will do this?

Comment: You could try to `.join('')` the array, so it becomes one big string, then search inside that.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I will lost indexes inside the array and in my case the TextNode I'm in.

Comment: Create a copy of the array that is joined, as @RocketHazmat suggested, and then use `.indexOf()` to find the position of the text.  Then use that and parse the array, checking the length of each individual string so you can see if the text came from 1 element or more.  It's a bit of a faff but it's not rocket science.  You should be able to give it a try and then come back with some code if you have trouble :)

Comment: @Archer thanks I was able to make it work with `join` and `indexOf`.

Comment: Glad it helped, and good on you for sorting it out :)